# Logstash / Elasticsearch: "Failed to install template" / " Got response code '400' "

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm new with ELK stack, i'm trying to install a template from logstash output.elasticsearch but when i'm put a "mappings" key in my JSON i have this issue:

```
[2020-09-12T15:19:04,321][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed to install template. {:message=>"Got response code '400' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/_template/maillog'", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:80:in `perform_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:291:in `perform_request_to_url'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:278:in `block in perform_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:373:in `with_connection'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:277:in `perform_request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:285:in `block in Pool'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:352:in `template_put'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:86:in `template_install'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:28:in `install'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:16:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:130:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-10.1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:51:in `block in setup_after_successful_connection'"]}
```

Here my JSON template:

```json
{
  "index_patterns": "*-maillog-*",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "refresh_interval": "10s",
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "maillog": {
      "properties": {
        "ip": { "type": "ip" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here my output.elasticsearch:

```json
output {
     elasticsearch {
        id => "test"
        index => "%{[product]}-maillog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        hosts => ["###ELASTIC_HOST###:9200"]
        document_type => "maillog"
        manage_template => true
        template_overwrite => true
        template => "${CONF_PATH}/mapping/maillog.json"
        template_name => "maillog"
      }
}
```

With this conf elastic can't create my template but if i remove "mappings" key from the template, like this:

```json
{
  "index_patterns": "*-maillog-*",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "refresh_interval": "10s",
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
    }
  }
}
```

There is no issue anymore.

My stack is composed from 3 containers :

```
elasticsearch 7.4.2

logstash 7.4.2

kibana 7.4.2
```

I'm probably missing something, but many hours spent and no clue to resolve this issue...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using elasticsearch version 7.X which does not have [types](https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0) anymore.

The `mailog` after your `mappings` declaration would be your type in versions before 7.X, but this does not work on version 7.X anymore, you need to change your `mappings` to the one bellow.

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "ip": { "type": "ip" }
    }  
}
```

Also, you can remove the `document_type` in your `elasticsearch` output in Logstash, this does not work anymore.

Comment: It works ! Thank you a lot @leandrojmp, I missed this detail...